# Visual Studio 2010 overwriting web.config without encoding

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-config

So I have a problem where Visual Studio 2010 overwrites web.config file by itself, and it changes my XML header option to not include encoding, it just deletes it, and reformats the whole web.config file.

Note, this only happens when I start to debug my program.

I've tried messing with multiple settings so far, with no success. 
Only thing I found to be working is entering the web.config file every time and clicking undo.
File is set to be UTF-8 already.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
gets overwritten to
`<?xml version="1.0">`

I expect the output to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Thanks.

Comment: When it overwrite the web.config? While build or while Publish?

Comment: When I start debugging it.